# More efficient sed on huge input files

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I regularly have to reduce huge db sql dumps (more than 100gb) down to more manageable file sizes by removing unnecessary INSERT statements. I do that with the following script.
I'm concerned that my script involves iterating multiple times through the source file, which is obviously computationally expensive.
Is there a way to combine all my SED statements into one, so the source file only needs to be processed once, or can be processed in a more efficient way?

```
sed '/INSERT INTO `attendance_log`/d' input.sql | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `analytics_models_log`/d' | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `backup_logs`/d' | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `config_log`/d' | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `course_completion_log`/d' | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `errorlog`/d' | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `log`/d' | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `logstore_standard_log`/d' | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `mnet_log`/d' | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `portfolio_log`/d' | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `portfolio_log`/d' | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `prog_completion_log`/d' | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `local_amosdatasend_log_entry`/d' | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `totara_sync_log`/d' | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `prog_messagelog`/d' | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `stats_daily`/d' | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `course_modules_completion`/d' | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `question_attempt_step_data`/d' | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `scorm_scoes_track`/d' | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `question_attempts`/d' | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `grade_grades_history`/d' | \
sed '/INSERT INTO `task_log`/d' > reduced.sql
```

Is this idea going in the right direction?

```
cat input.sql | sed '/INSERT INTO `analytics_models_log`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `backup_logs`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `config_log`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `course_completion_log`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `errorlog`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `log`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `logstore_standard_log`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `mnet_log`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `portfolio_log`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `portfolio_log`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `prog_completion_log`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `local_amosdatasend_log_entry`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `totara_sync_log`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `prog_messagelog`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `stats_daily`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `course_modules_completion`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `question_attempt_step_data`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `scorm_scoes_track`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `question_attempts`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `grade_grades_history`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `task_log`/d' > reduced.sql
```

Comment: I guess you already looked at where these logs come from and concluded that it is not possible to configure the logger to not add them to this file? The next step will be to test the `sed`, `grep`and `awk` solutions proposed in the answers and select the fastest. I would personally also try to code a dedicated filter in C, just in case it would be even better than these more generic tools. Anyway, if you do this, please come back here and share your observations. It is very interesting and could help others.

Comment: it would definitely help performance to get rid of the multiple subprocesses (one for each `| sed`), even though these are working on a single pass through the source file; single passes through the file can be handled via `grep`, `sed -e/-e/-e`, `sed -f`, `awk` and ... ? next question will be maintenance of the list of SQL commands to remove ... hardcoding in your script will be a headache vs maintaining a (config/list) file of what to remove; as Renaud Pacalet has mentioned ... **not** generating the (unwanted) `INSERT INTO` commands in the first place would likely be a (better) solution

Comment: If there are many other SQL statements than `INSERT INTO ...` in the log file, it could be interesting to filter first by that to see if it improves the performance. With `sed`, for instance, I'd probably try something like `/INSERT INTO / {/INSERT INTO attendance_log/d;...}`. And if these patterns are supposed to match at the beginning of the line I would definitely let `sed` know: `/^INSERT INTO / {/^INSERT INTO attendance_log/d;...}`. Can you please add more information about your logs (`INSERT INTO` only, beginning of line...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple `sed ... | sed ...` you can combine them by writing `sed -e ... -e ...` or `sed ...;...`. But in this case there is an even more efficient method:

```
sed -E '/INSERT INTO `(attendance_log|analytics_models_log|...)`/d'
```

Alternatively, switch to `grep` which *could* be even faster:

```
grep -vE 'INSERT INTO `(attendance_log|analytics_models_log|...)`'
```

or

```
grep -vFf <(printf 'INSERT INTO `%s`\n' attendance_log analytics_models_log ...)
```

You could even try to replace all `..._log` and `logs` with a regex, if this is what you want. With this, you only have to explicitly list the non-log files:

```
INSERT INTO `([^`]*logs?|local_amosdatasend_log_entry|stats_daily|...)`
```

Comment: This was the correct answer. I converted a 15GB db down to 1.5GB in 7 minutes with the grep -vE technique:

```cat input.sql | grep -vE 'INSERT INTO `(table1|table2)`'  > reduced.sql```

Thank you!

Comment: Additionally, a 150GB sql file was reduced to 14GB in 76 minutes using this method. I think that's pretty fast now!

Comment: @StiofanMac I'm glad you are happy. But 76 minutes seems pretty slow for such a basic command; even on a 14GB file. Maybe `LC_ALL=C grep -vE '...' input.sql > reduced.sql` runs faster. If you know that `INSERT INTO` always is at the start of the line, use `'^INSERT ...'` as a faster regex. For more speed, split the file into chunks and process them in parallel (programs like GNU `parallel` or `split` can do this for you).

Comment: @Socowi could you add some information on what the flags do and why they are faster?

Comment: @cerved I *could*, but that would make the answer longer for no reason. Everyone can look the options up in `man` or https://explainshell.com/. ¶ In this case, neither *option* makes the command faster. The commands in this answer are faster because they are invoked only once instead of 20 times like OP did.

Comment: @Socowi imho the quality of the answer would be improved if it were self contained. All nix environments don't have `man` and ironically https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=sed+-E gives no information.

Comment: @CervEd I used to think the same, but nowadays I prefer short answers. As a reader, this additional information often annoys me. Most oft the time, it is just noise that makes it harder to find what I am searching for. Maybe you can see my point if you imagined an actually "self contained" answer. It would also explain `sed`, `grep`, command line interfaces (here `sh`), text files, and even computers in general. But if you want to invest the time, feel free to edit this answer. I'll accept the edit if you add the additional information at the end.

Comment: @Socowi I don't thin I sagree. Most of the time is an extra step in figuring out which flavor of `sed|awk|grep|xargs|rsync|...` is being used.

Comment: @Socowi It's an unnecessary extra step in trying to figure out why the answer is the way it is. Nobody is talking about explaining computers. Simple things like writing long-forms `--regexp-extended`. Explaining why using `ERE` instead of `BRE` is relevant go a long way. In this case we're talking about tools with stable APIs but lots of times you find yourself looking at a top-voted obsolete answer. And if they don't include details/background you're left to guess the reasoning of a stranger on the internet

Answer (score 2):

For ease of maintenance it may make sense to have a list of tables (in a file) that `awk` can use to filter the SQL script.

List of the (database) tables to skip ...

```
$ cat table.list
attendance_log
analytics_models_log
backup_logs
config_log
course_completion_log
```

Sample SQL script:

```
$ cat sample.sql
INSERT INTO attendance_log ...
INSERT INTO bubblegum ...
INSERT INTO backup_logs ...
INSERT INTO more_nonsense ...
```

Let `awk` do the pruning for us:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {table[$1];next} /^INSERT INTO / && $3 in table{next}1' table.list sample.sql
INSERT INTO bubblegum ...
INSERT INTO more_nonsense ...
```

**NOTES:**

- this is based solely on the fact the question **only** mentions `INSERT INTO` commands
- I'm **assuming** the lines (of interest) **start** with `INSERT INTO` (otherwise remove the `^`)
- this solution will need additional checks/coding to address other SQL statements OP wants to remove

Comment: Before using this solution, that could delete other lines than just the `INSERT INTO ...`, it would be wise to check that these table names cannot be found in field 3 of other SQL statements.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet good point; have updated question to hardcode the `INSERT INTO ` for now; OP can always come back and modify to address other SQL statements

Comment: IMHO the best approach, just needs a small tweak: the OPs table names in the question are within backtick delimiters so in the sample SQL script ```INSERT INTO attendance_log ...``` should really be ```INSERT INTO `attendance_log` ...```, for example, and in the awk script `table[$1]` should be `table["\047"$1"\047"]`.

Answer (score 1):

For ease of maintenance it may make sense to have a list of `INSERT INTO <table>/d` commands (in a file) that `sed` can use to filter the SQL script.

Storing the `sed` commands in a file, eg:

```
$ cat sed.cmds
/INSERT INTO attendance_log/d
/INSERT INTO analytics_models_log/d
/INSERT INTO backup_logs/d
/INSERT INTO config_log/d
/INSERT INTO course_completion_log/d
```

Sample SQL script:

```
$ cat sample.sql
INSERT INTO attendance_log ...
INSERT INTO bubblegum ...
INSERT INTO backup_logs ...
INSERT INTO more_nonsense ...
```

Invoking the file of `sed` commands:

```
$ sed -f sed.cmds sample.sql
INSERT INTO bubblegum ...
INSERT INTO more_nonsense ...
```